# How to get random values with twig including same file multiple times

Tags: random, include, twig

I'm trying to figure out, how to include one template multiple times with different random values.

I do have a template:

```
<div class="include-1">
  {% include 'include.twig' %}
</div>
<div class="include-2">
  {% include 'include.twig' %}
</div>
<div class="include-3">
  {% include 'include.twig' %}
</div>
```

Inside the include.twig I have:

```
<span>
  {{ random(10) }}
</span>
```

Expected result (numbers in span should be random in range from 0–10):

```
<div class="include-1">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="include-2">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="include-3">
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Actual result (the first include get the random value, but then it is just "cached"):

```
<div class="include-1">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="include-2">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="include-3">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
```

I've tested include, embed etc. but with no avail.
I'm looking for a twig based solution. Cannot touch PHP.
As a fallback I can do it with JS, but was interested if such a thing can be done it Twig.

Question:

Is there a way how to force Twig to re-render the include before each include?

Comment: is not so easy to replicate... here works fine https://twigfiddle.com/1pk3db

Comment: try passing the random value as argument to the included template so probably will be reprocessed...

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the random number function as a value on each of your include statements, such as:

```
<div class="include-1">
    {% include 'include.twig' with {'random': random(10) } %}
</div>
```

Then, inside your `include.twig` file:

```
<span>{{ random }}</span>
```

This will generate the random number for each include you do, and should give you the result you're after.